# Set SAP RFC import table parameter using PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php, saprfc

I am trying to call a SAP RFC function which has import parameters as a table. Currently I am using SAP RFC for communication between SAP and PHP but it is not accepting table in import parameter.

It is giving following error for import parameter EX_ORDER_HEADER:

> Can't find interface name EX_ORDER_HEADER, __cal_refresh_internal_buffer();

Comment: Without the function module signature and the calling code, I doubt that anyone would be able to help.

Comment: Are you sure this is an import parameter? EX_ORDER_HEADER gives a hint of an export parameter, not an import table.