# Pass table as import parameter to SAP RFC using PHP

Tags: php, saprfc

I want to pass data to SAP RFC having table as import parameters using PHP.

I am using `saprfc` library but its functions don't provide the desired functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set SAP RFC import table parameter using php multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078015/set-sap-rfc-import-table-parameter-using-php-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of your earlier question, and with even less details than before.

Comment: I am getting warning:  CALDBG: Can't find interface name IM_ITEM, __cal_set() here IM_ITEM is an import parameter as a table for accepting data in multiple rows.

Comment: All I want is to pass data in single call not by looping the call function.